# How to use XSLT on file upload ASP.Net MVC

Tags: xslt

I need to be able to upload a KML file on file upload, transform it to GML using XSLT and then save it to my SQL 2008 database. I'm not sure how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public ActionResult Create(GeoRegion georegion, HttpPostedFileBase Polygon)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            if (Polygon.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Polygon.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                Polygon.SaveAs(path);

            }




            db.GeoRegions.Add(georegion);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(georegion);
    }
```

Comment: If you have not already done so, I'd recommend reading [this article](http://spanring.eu/blog/2005/12/11/kml2gml/) by Christian Spanring.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create the XslCompiledTransform object
var transform = new XslCompiledTransform(); 

// Load the stylesheet file
transform.Load(xslFilePath);                

// Transform the XML file and store the output
transform.Transform(sourceFilePath, targetFilePath);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx

Comment: How can I save the transformed xml to the database?

Comment: There's a fairly sophisticated way of doing it here: http://mscerts.programming4.us/sql_server/sql%20server%202008%20%20%20developing%20custom%20managed%20database%20objects%20%28part%203%29%20-%20developing%20managed%20user-defined%20functions.aspx.  However, [study the output options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0610k0w4.aspx) for XslCompiledTransform.  Presumably, you'd want to store the output in an XML field in the SQL Server database.  Use the Stream or TextWriter output option, and write the resulting output to your new database field.